# Syntax of += for immutable Set

Tags: scala

For a mutable Set += method (operator) will have side effect and changes the set itself. As an example:

```
val mySet = scala.collection.mutable.Set(1, 2, 3)
mySet += 4
```

In the above example a new instance of Set is not created, but the existing one mutated. += is an actual method of mutable Set, so we can write the last line as:

```
mySet.+=(4)
```

However for immutable Set when we use += a new Set instance is created:

```
var myOtherSet = Set(1, 2, 3)
myOtherSet += 4
```

Why += is not an actual method of immutable Set even though we use it like a method that is applied to Set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is that based on the book I am reading why `+=` is not an actual method of immutable `Set` even though we use it as a method that is applied to `Set`?

There is no `+=` method for immutable `Set`s (or any other immutable collection).

The rule is that an operator assignment expression of the form `a ω= b` is first interpreted as `a.ω=(b)` if that type-checks, but if it doesn't type-check, then it alternatively gets interpreted as `a = a ω b` (provided *that* type-checks).

So, the reason `myOtherSet += 4` works, is that there is a `+` method defined, `myOtherSet` is a `var`, and the expression gets interpreted as `myOtherSet = myOtherSet + 4`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Didn't get what type-check means for an object and how we can know an object type checks or not? Maybe by type-check you mean  a method named ω= is defined for the object?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a *var*, then += stands for an assignment and +, i.e. x += y gets translated to x = x + y. In this case += is not a method, but syntactic sugar. Except, if there is an explicit += method defined.

This does not only hold for Set, but for all types. Consider the following example:

```
case class NewInt(var x : Int) {  
  def +(y: Int) = { println("+"); NewInt(x + y) }
}

var n = NewInt(3)
n += 3 // outputs +, n == NewInt(6) now
val n2 = NewInt(3)
n2 += 3 // error

case class SuperInt(var x : Int) {
  def +=(y: Int) = { println("+="); x = x + y }
  def +(y: Int) = { println("+"); SuperInt(x + y) }
}

var n3 = SuperInt(3)
n3 += 3 // outputs +=, n3 == SuperInt(6)
val n4 = SuperInt(3)
n4 += 3 // outputs +=, n4 == SuperInt(6)
```

Comment: I agree += that means an assignment can only be applied to a var since we can not mutate a val however the way it is interpreted depends on weather the object has a += method itself or not and not var or val definition of the parameter. So if a val has a += method it will be translated to that method instead of assignment and likely returns error, feel free to disagree if am wrong :)

Comment: That is what my example shows and my text describes. Maybe the "Except" clause is hard to read/understand, but that is how rules are sometimes defined.

Answer (score 1):

> why can't we call it an actual method of immutable Set?

Most obviously because no method `+=` is defined in the immutable `Set` class or any of its super classes (nor any class for which an implicit conversion exists).

It also acts differently in some respects than methods do:

- You can only use `+=` if `myOtherSet` is a `var` instead of a `val`. You also can't use it on anything other than a variable. Methods can be used on any type of expression that evaluated to the method's class regardless of whether it's a `val`, a `var` or some other type of expression.
- `+=` on a `var` that contains an immutable object will make the variable point to a different object (because obviously you can't change the object itself). So after you do `myOtherSet += 4`, the identity of `myOtherSet` changes. A method can never do that.

Comment: MyOtherSet+=4 is converted to myOtherSet = myOtherSet + 4 and + operator for both mutable and immutable set returns a new set. In this case +=a for immutable set is translated to x = x + a so returns a new set so we can only use var for it. In summary the way += is interpreted depends on object itself(weather it has a += method) and not var or val I think.

Comment: @iman "myOtherSet += 4" is not converted to `myOtherSet = myOtherSet + 4` for mutable sets. It just calls the `+=` method on the mutable set. "In summary the way += is interpreted depends on object itself(weather it has a += method) and not var or val I think." Right, but if `+=` is interpreted as an assignment, we can't use it on a `val`. And that's one difference between `+=` the re-assignment operator and `+=` the method.